# Set time with Python Arrow

Tags: python, arrow-python

Do you know how I can set time using Python Arrow to today at 00:00:00 and to *now* in localtime.
With *time* library I do something similar but in UTC:

```
from_date_str   = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00")
to_date_str     = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

thanks.

Comment: https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ hope this will help you

Comment: @SundeepPidugu actually I was already checking that, it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved with

```
arrow.now('Europe/Amsterdam').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```